# Clarify celestial-mechanics tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

The [celestial-mechanics](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/celestial-mechanics) tag implies that planetary orbital mechanics are on-topic for space.SE. I would like to edit the description of the tag to clarify that it is intended for **spacecraft only**. However, I ask here first to be sure that it is the intention of both the tag and the site members that this be the case.

Comment: In the context of interactions between celestial bodies and spacecraft, rather.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Questions regarding the movements and interactions of astronomical bodies as it relates to spacecraft, their trajectories, and their maneuvers."

Feel free to edit.

Comment: Thanks Jerard. Looks good to me!